# I want to add Printable View Functionality in Custom Button

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, printable

Is it Possible to add Printable View Functionality as a Custom Button which means when i click on button it shows printable view with all associated information of objects

I prefer to go ahead without visualforce coding or if its not possible can you please provide the coding.

Regards,
Hareesh

[image: Printable View Functionality]

Answer (score 1):

Add a new custom button on your object with the type URL and use the below:

```
/{!Case.Id}/p?retURL=/{!Case.Id}
```

Replacing {!Case.Id} with the object of your choice.

[image]

Comment: Hi Guys, This works when i have only one section if i have multiple section and want to merge data for all in printable view  how can i proceed